# Python EasyList Processor/Parser

Tags: python, parsing, processor

Are there any processors/parsers for EasyList that are written in python?
http://easylist.adblockplus.org/en/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! Like a month later :(

http://adblockplus.org/en/filters

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is, in python.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/adblockparser

Answer (score -3):

Apparently not, according to Google.

The [EasyList structure](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt) is pretty straightforward, I bet you you can knock up a parser in less time than it takes to search. Recognize domain names, strip out trailing resource-strings with ^, it all looks easy.

There is [Ned Batchelder's list of parsers from 2004](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/python-parsers.html).

Comment: It's actually not really that easy. Their format is not straight forward by any means, they created their own regex-type syntax which is parsed and compiled into more efficient regular expressions at runtime. It gets even more insane once you start combining rules, (which many are combined), exceptions, so on and so forth.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire : combining rules is sort of an extra requirement. Anyway sorry this is all I know, I've never used it myself.